# Javascript stop second setTimeOut function

Tags: javascript

I have a **JS library** where on submit form `setTimeOut` function executes.

I want to execute another `setTimeOut` function before or after form submission and don't want to execute the `setTimeOut` function that is in the JS library on submit event.

I can not/don't want to declare like `myVar = setTimeout` in library so that later I can use `clearTimeout(myVar);` to clear the timeout function in the library from my end.

Any idea?

For example:

### library.js

Form submit event handler with timeout function

### contact.html

```
$('#contact').submit();
setTimeout(function() {
    //some tasks here and dont execute library.js timeout function
}, 5);
```

Comment: what is the libry ?doesn't it provide methods to stop timeout ?

Comment: can you share your code snippet?

Comment: I build a JS library for form handling and there I set a timeout function for some tasks. In a page say contact.html I say like this $('#contact').submit() and it fires library form submit event. I want before or after $('#contact').submit() execute a timeout function so that the timeout function in the library will not execute

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any good solution but I have now a temporary solution just increase the timer+1. Means if we have 1000ms in library as mentioned in the question, I run another timeout function with 10001ms